# Cross Domain Facebook getJson jQuery not bringing back data

Tags: jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

Is there any reason at this doesnt work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=cinema&type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000";
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
</script>
```

I should point out, that it doesnt return anything, not that its bringing back the wrong results, none are returned.

is it because it's cross domain or not?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Firebug for debugging?  Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Turns out if you append "&callback=?" to the end, it brings back an object with "error: use oauth". I assumed this was public data and wouldnt require authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-domain requests require using JSONP. Either add a `callback=` URL parameter (if the web API supports it) or use `jQuery.ajax` with the `dataType: "jsonp"` parameter (search the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation for "dataType").

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in an error argument in the function (function(data,error,er) and alert these as well to try and capture the problem.